# android xml design cache

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, caching

Is it possible to cache xml design in android? Basically what I wanted is that the first time I load the activity, it loads some data from SQLite database and then displays it on the listview. When I view the activity again, the data displayed on the listview will not load again from the SQLite but instead from the cache of xml design more of like a snapshot of the activity. I want this for a faster performance. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say, you want to cache the whole inflated listview which is populated from db during the event of destroying the parent activity, so that in the next time, you don't need to fetch data again i.e. you are looking to reuse previously inflated listview?

If that is the question, no it is not possible & even if it were possible by some hooks or crooks, you must not. As inflated views are highly coupled with context, you try to reuse the inflated views in above described way, then the previous corrupted non-existing context will hopefully gift you a fatal exception.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for answering and sharing your thoughts about this. I get your point. But what if the inflated listview populated from SQLite database is not subject to destroying the activity? What I mean for viewing purposes only? For example on the first activity contains a button going to the second activity for viewing the listview. And then when I go back to the second activity the second time around, it will automatically inflate to the listview without the need of SQLite. Is sharedprefences, onresume, onpause, onsavedinstancestate an option?

Comment: in your imaginary case, for the first time, when you are returning from second activity to first activity, activity switching will occur between from second to first activity & your second activity will be destroyed. Next time when you are going to second activity again, its basically a new activity instance again (activity context are different).  I hope you got my point.
Now as you are using sqlite, I assume your data is sufficiently large. So in this case, shared preference is not an option. And onPause(), onResume() are activity states only. They only offer suitable time window.

Comment: Hello sir for the last time, if you may leave me with some suggestions, what would you do for a scenario like this to have a faster performance? I mean is there any other way around to accomplish this task?

Comment: My best guess for your case would be, I would save the fetched data in a public static variable of another class (lets say CacheStorage.DB_DATA_LIST), and when populating the list view, I would check out that static variable first if there is already. If not, then I would fetch from db and store in the public static variable. This approach is generally described as loading once in the memory & reusing until the next garbage memory collection.

Comment: Great approach. Thanks for sharing your thoughts sir. :)